# Ordenamiento por burbuja. (Números)

Tags: c, ordenamiento

espero se encuentre bien. Mi programa genera 10 números aleatorios y después los ordena por el método Burbuja pero si pongo un rango de números aleatorios mayor a 101 (entre 101 - 110) me arroga el numero 44 al ordenarlo por el método Burbuja pero el numero 44 no esta en el arreglo de los diez números generados automáticamente, de donde sale el numero 44. Este es el código fuente.(Nota: si cambio el rango por números menores a cien si lo ordena correctamente).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
int main(){
    int vector[10],i,j,aux;
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Lista de numeros aleatorios:\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        vector[i] = 100 + rand()% (110+1-100);
        printf("%d ",vector[i]);
    }
    
    
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        for(j=0;j<10;j++){
            if(vector[j] > vector[j+1]){
                aux = vector[j];
                vector[j] = vector[j+1];
                vector[j+1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nLa lista de numeros ordenados por Burbuja es: \n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("%d\n",vector[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Los resultados de la ejecución de tu programa son impredecibles porque estás accediendo a zonas de memoria que no has inicializado/reservado tú, gcc (o los compiladores en general) generan rutinas por defecto (de ensamblador) para detectar este tipo de desbordamientos, cuando yo ejecuto tu código a veces me salta el típico `core dumped`. El algoritmo de la burbuja no es exactamente lo que hace tu código, recuerda que por cada iteración que hagas en el primer bucle (habiendo ejecutado el bucle más interno) hay al menos un elemento que ya queda en su posición final, y es por esto que el último elemento no debería de volverse a comprobar.

Te adjunto una versión corregida de tu ódigo que funciona correctamente:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

#define SIZE 10

int main(){
    int vector[SIZE],i,j,aux;
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Lista de numeros aleatorios:\n");
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        vector[i] = 100 + rand()% (110+1-100);
        printf("%d ",vector[i]);
    }
    
    
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        for(j=0;j<SIZE-i-1;j++){
            if(vector[j] > vector[j+1]){
                aux = vector[j];
                vector[j] = vector[j+1];
                vector[j+1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nLa lista de numeros ordenados por Burbuja es: \n");
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        printf("%d\n",vector[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```